# Cart Product Image From External Source

Tags: cart, product-images

I have products that have an attribute for an external image location.  When one of these products is added to the cart, I would like the cart thumbnail to to be replaced by this external image file.

Because I'm making this as part of an extension, for compatibly/portability reasons I really do not want to edit

> /template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml

I would rather just make it so when

> $this->getProductThumbnail()->resize(75)

is called it knows to look for the external URL first, and display that if it's there.

I wanted to override

> Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Item_Renderer:getProductThumbnail()

but then resize doesn't work properly.

Any ideas or help implementing this would be awesome.  I know there must be some way to do it because there are extensions that allow all images to be moved to S3.  Essentially it's the same idea.  I think.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you updated external image attribute in function :public function getProductThumbnail()
    {
        if (!is_null($this->_productThumbnail)) {
            return $this->_productThumbnail;
        }
        return $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail');
    }???

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "have I updated it".  I would like to just return the external link there, but I can't because in the cart getProductThumbnail()->resize(75) is used.  I can't call resize if just a string is being returned.

Comment: can you please add your codes in the question?